# How to add nonce to inline styles and scripts in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Assuming `Content-Security-Policy` policy such as:

```
default-src 'self'; script-src https://ray.run
```

Next.js fails to function because of errors such as:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-zu3j41gcw4FOWZYIiUz/VyL9HYakAfKLQFMCEcWNkAc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://ray.run". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-qJ8ozvdSL8lvQo3N0L0SYjL5lY0bLZcaD/xXL4BlEpQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

As per what the error suggests, I have two options: allow "unsafe-inline" or add `nonce`. However, reading Next.js documentation I cannot find any mention of how to `nonce` to the inlined styles and scripts.

For context, I am using [next.js13](/questions/tagged/next.js13) with React Server Component (RSC).

Comment: We now have official documentation for handling nonces and Content Security Policy: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy

Answer (score 5):

To add the `nonce` attribute to `<script>` and `<styles>` tags, you need to define the `content-security-policy` header in the `middleware.ts` file (works with `next@13.4.0` and higher).

The header is parsed by Next.js ([in the `renderToHTMLOrFlight` function](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/server/app-render/app-render.tsx#L1233-L1238)) to extract the `nonce` value, which is then added to the generated HTML tags.

Here's an example of the `middleware` function:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const nonce = crypto.randomUUID();
  const csp = `script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';`;

  // Clone the request headers
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);

  // Set the CSP header so that Next.js can read it and generate tags with the nonce
  requestHeaders.set('content-security-policy', csp);

  // Create new response
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // New request headers
      headers: requestHeaders
    }
  });

  // Also set the CSP header in the response so that it is outputted to the browser
  response.headers.set('content-security-policy', csp);

  return response;
}
```

If necessary, you can also add a custom request header to read the `nonce` value in your pages:

```js
requestHeaders.set('x-nonce', nonce);
```

To go further, according to the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce):

> Nonces should be generated differently each time the page loads (nonce only once!).

This means you can't set it in the `next.config.js` file, as it will only be generated once at build time. In the `middleware` function, the `nonce` value will be regenerated for each request.

Last but not least, **this only works with [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)** and not with static rendering, since the `nonce` value must be different for each page load.

---

Code originaly published by [@danieltott](https://github.com/danieltott) on GitHub: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43743#issuecomment-1542684019

Related discussions:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43710
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49648

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional info, If you add nonce and generate a lighthouse report it will still complain: "Consider adding 'unsafe-inline' (ignored by browsers supporting nonces/hashes) to be backward compatible with older browsers.", and the severity for this one is labeled as Medium. In my case, I added both the nonce and the unsafe-inline.